# recuperar funcionalidad del botón ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que me guarda los registros. La primera vez que guardo lo hace sin problema, sin embargo, al hacerlo por segunda vez, el botón no funciona, de manera que me veo obligado a refrescar la página manualmente para poder guardar otro registro.

```
<form id='mvc-form2' method='post'>

        <div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="apellido1">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="apellido2">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary save"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i><p>Añadir</p></a>

</form>
```

Y aquí tengo mi JS:

```
var Controller = Class.extend({
    formId: "#mvc-form2",

    initEvents: function () {

        this.log("initEvents()");
        var me = this;

        $(me.formId).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: "focus",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeFirstDay: false,
        });

    },

    init: function () {
        this.log("init()");
        var me = this;

        $(me.formId).on("click", ".save", function () {

            var $element = $(me.formId);

            var data = [];
            data = generateDataFields($element, data, false);

            console.log(data);

            me.nextStepEnable = false;


            $.ajax({
                url: "/controlador/save/",
                method: "post",
                data: data,
                success: function (html) {
                    ajaxActionSuccess();
                    $(me.bloqueDondePinto).html(html);
                    me.initEvents();
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

var controller;

$(document).ready(function () {
    controller = new Controller();
});
```

La primera vez me guarda el registro, sin embargo, para guardar un segundo registro, debo refrescar manualmente la página. 
¿Alguien sabe como refrescarla en segundo plano (sin que me pregunte si estoy seguro de que quiero reenviar el formulario)? 
¿O alguien sabe por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el problema que te comenta el compañero pero la solución es:

```js
$(me.formId).on("click", ".save", function(e){
e.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
  url: "/controlador/metodoQueGuarda/",
  method: "post",
  data: data,
  success: function (html) {
    ajaxActionSuccess();
    $(me.bloqueDondeMuestroElRegistro.html(html);
    me.initEvents();
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary save">
```

Si lo quieres hacer con Jquery

Y:

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary save">
```

Si lo quieres hacer con html

Comment: trato de hacerlo con jQuey pero la única diferencia que veo es el e.preventDefault(). Y sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: pero que quieres que se recargue la pagina o que se limpie el form y no se recargue?

Comment: quiero seguir guardando registros sin tener que recargar la página manualmente. No sé si para eso hay que recargar la página en segundo plano o simplemente inicializar de nuevo la funcionalidad del botón.

Comment: que yo sepa no tienes que hacer nada simplemente creo que ejecutas la funcion con el disparador incorrecto.... que es me.formid?

Comment: me = this, formid es el id del formulario del que recojo los datos.

Comment: si el disparador fuese incorrecto... tampoco debería funcionar la primera vez no?

Comment: edita y pon mas codigo html

Comment: editado todo de nuevo.

Comment: pues nose que te falla tio cuando estableces el form lo la funcion la llamas con ajax, y cuando se ejecuta ya puedes volver a crear otro.... rellenas campos das a save y te deberia de guardar otro no veo el error ahora mismo leugo lo miro mas despacio que voy con el movil

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, repondiendo a tu pregunta para recargar la página web debes agregar `location.reload();` al final de `success` o en `complete` como muestra el código.

```
$(me.formId).on("click", ".save", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      url: "/controlador/metodoQueGuarda/",
      method: "post",
      data: data,
      success: function (html) {
        ajaxActionSuccess();
        $(me.bloqueDondeMuestroElRegistro.html(html);
        me.initEvents();
      },
      complete:function(){
          location.reload();
      }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ya he probado esa función. Recarga la página automáticamente, pero no de manera asíncrona, por lo que no me sirve...

Comment: Estimado, prueba colocar al final del success este codigo `$('#miFormulario')[0].reset();` me dices si funciona.